# Exporting namespaced data from vault and getting error

Tags: migration, hashicorp-vault

I need to migrate data from one vault instance to another. The data is stored in kv engines which are stored within childnamespaces under a non root namespace.I want to preserve the namespace paths and the kv secrets but unsure if its possible

I tried like the below to list the secrets even and it doesnt seem to work

```
vault kv list secret/ -namespace=productname/envname/application-namespace/service-name
```

productname is the parent namespace and the rest are child namespaces which my application creates dynamically.
Under the child namespace service-name there is a kv engine called "secret" which has a lot of secrets.

Worst case scenario I can recreate all the child namespaces of each product manually but I will need to export and import the contents of the "secret" kv engine at least.

However when I run that command I get

```
Too many arguments (expected 1, got 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, because I've seen tools to do this, but I found a solution a few years ago.

Again, I don't know if this will help you in this case.

But my method works very well for migrating a vault to another vault.

Installation of the tool

On machine with old vault ( it can be the same machine with the new vault ):

1. Dowload safe tools :

> ```
> wget https://github.com/starkandwayne/safe/releases/download/v1.6.1/safe-linux-amd64
> ```

2. Target the old vault url :

> `safe target http://vault.qpm.sncoia.lan vaultold`

3. Authenficate to the old vault :

> `safe auth token`

4. Export Token :

> `safe export -T http://adress.oldvault.lan > export.json`

Import ur secret to the new vault :

1. Target the old vault url :

> `safe target http://address.of.the.new.vault vaultnew`

2. Authenficate to the old vault :

> `safe auth token`

3. Export Token :

> `Safe import < export.json`